# How to catch mwclient errors in pybind11?

Tags: pybind11

How would I go about catching mwclient errors in pybind11? I am specifically looking to catch mwclient.ProtectedPageError and mwclient.EditError (in that order). I am asking since python exceptions seem to just be considered py::error_already_set in C++, and was wondering if this was possible.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Are you asking how to catch python exceptions in C++ ?

Comment: How to catch specific python exceptions included in an external php library